# SQL parsing XML with repeating structure

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am trying to figure out how to process XML a repeating structure. In the below example, Mr. Smith should have two children (Mike and Tom) and Ms. Magoo should have no children. Tom, Mr. Smith's child has a child named Sally who is Mr. Smith's grandchild. Ms. Magoo, not having any children, also does not have any grandchildren.

```
DECLARE @tableXML table (
ID int NOT NULL,
XMLdata xml NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @testXML xml
SET @testXML =
'<parent>
    <name>Mr. Smith</name>
    <child>
        <name>Mike</name>
        <child />
    </child>
    <child>
        <name>Tom</name>
        <child>
            <name>Sally</name>
        </child>
    </child>
</parent>
<parent>
    <name>Ms. Magoo</name>
    <child>
        <name />
        <child />
    </child>
</parent>'

INSERT INTO @tableXML VALUES
 (1, @testXML);

SELECT 
    IsNull(parent.p.value('self::node()','varchar(100)'),Null) AS [Parent],
    IsNull(children.c.value('self::node()','varchar(100)'),Null) AS [Child],
    IsNull(grandChildren.g.value('self::node()','varchar(100)'),Null) AS [Grandchild]
FROM @tableXML
CROSS APPLY XMLdata.nodes('/parent/name') AS parent (p)
CROSS APPLY parent.p.nodes('/parent/child/name') AS children (c)
CROSS APPLY children.c.nodes('/parent/child/child/name') AS grandChildren (g)
```

The result set of the above is:

```
Parent   |  Child  | Grandchild
---------------------------------
Mr. Smith   Mike      Sally
Mr. Smith   Tom       Sally
Mr. Smith             Sally
Ms. Magoo   Mike      Sally
Ms. Magoo   Tom       Sally
Ms. Magoo             Sally
```

The result should be:

```
Parent   |  Child  | Grandchild
---------------------------------
Mr. Smith   Mike      
Mr. Smith   Tom       Sally
Ms. Magoo
```

Thoughts?

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: Great, that you provided some *copy'n'paste* test code! +1 from my side

Comment: Is this limited in depth (in this case: 3 levels), or are you looking for a generic approach (might Sally have children too)?

Comment: Btw: What about the `IsNull()`? If it's `NULL` you return `NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

Try it in this way:

> ```
> SELECT 
>     p2.lin.value('(./name)[1]','varchar(100)') AS [Parent],
>     p3.lin.value('self::node()','varchar(100)') AS [Child],
>     p3.lin.value('(./child)[1]','varchar(100)') AS [GrandChild]
> FROM @tableXML
> CROSS APPLY XMLdata.nodes('/parent') AS p2(lin)
> CROSS APPLY p2.lin.nodes('child') AS p3(lin)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Parent    | Child    | GrandChild
> :-------- | :------- | :---------
> Mr. Smith | Mike     |           
> Mr. Smith | TomSally | Sally     
> Ms. Magoo |          |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b637137b7f3edfbccd5e0d549d0a37bb)*

Comment: If Sally had a brother (one more child below "Tom"), you'd read the first in all cases. You are missing the `.nodes()` for the third level...

Answer (score 0):

You were close...

With `CROSS APPLY xyz.nodes()` you can dive deeper and deeper into nested structures. But you must think of this like of a relative address (a *current position*) within your tree.

With a line like

```
CROSS APPLY parent.p.nodes('/parent/child/name') AS children (c)
```

... you are reading right down from the root again, not starting at `parent.p`

Try it like this:

```
SELECT 
    IsNull(parent.p.value('(name/text())[1]','varchar(100)'),Null) AS [Parent],
    IsNull(children.c.value('(name/text())[1]','varchar(100)'),Null) AS [Child],
    IsNull(grandChildren.g.value('(name/text())[1]','varchar(100)'),Null) AS [Grandchild]
FROM @tableXML
CROSS APPLY XMLdata.nodes('/parent') AS parent (p)
CROSS APPLY parent.p.nodes('child') AS children (c)
CROSS APPLY children.c.nodes('child') AS grandChildren (g);
```